# babel-cli not working with latest preset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've executed the following line, and it compiles fine:

`babel src --out-dir lib --presets react,es2015`

But when I change `es2015` to `latest`, and run it:

`babel src --out-dir lib --presets react,latest`

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: [BABEL] src/MyComponent.js: Invalid options type for /Users/liadrian/Dev/react-reveal-text/node_modules/babel-preset-latest/lib/index.js
    at Logger.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:39:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:243:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:349:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:369:24
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:364:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:348:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:307:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:465:10)
    at File.initOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:194:75)
```

I find this to be very strange because I made sure to install the `latest` preset as is evidenced by the existence of the `node_modules/babel-preset-latest/` directory.

And everything works completely fine otherwise. What is it about the `latest` preset that is causing it to trip? I've tried all of the following presets and they work just fine: `es2015`, `es2016`, `es2017`. It's just the `latest` preset that is tripping everything up.

Any help on troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: My package versions

```
"babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
"babel-core": "^6.21.0",
"babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was using my globally installed `babel-cli` instead of using the locally installed one (which was the up-to-date one).

Everything worked smoothly once I ran it like this:

`node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js src --out-dir lib --presets react,latest`

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 3):

See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/_jayphelps/status/761411917814468610) by @_jayphelps:

> If u experience errors w/ babel like "Invalid options type for" or "Logger.error" or similar, upgrade babel-core! https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3635

So try upgrading `babel-core` and other Babel modules. You can do that with this command:

```
npm i -D babel-core@latest
```

`i` is a shortcut for `install`, `-D` adds the package to `devDependencies` in `package.json` (it's the same as `--save-dev`), and `@latest` installs the latest version available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried to do that, but the same thing seems to be happening. I've edited my original post with specific version numbers.